# Ionic OpenStreetMap Integration with Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, ionic3, openstreetmap

I am integrating Ionic App with OSM using Leaflet. I have  inside page.html file and the rest of the code is inside my page.ts file. So, I am not using @ViewChild() in order find that div. As, Leaflet's **L.map('map')** should find it. I am initializing my map on ionViewDidLoad and making heavy work in ionViewDidEnter such as converting osm data which is retrieved from post request to geoJSON data, then putting a lot of Markers on the map. I am kind of trying to release the resources in ionViewDidLeave making **this.map = null;**. Is this a right implementation? Who can advise something in terms of implementation. Because the page is kind of freezing when I scroll.

```
ionViewDidLoad() {
    this.map = L.map('map').setView([41.0131, 28.9641], 18);
    L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.fr/hot/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
      maxZoom: 18
    }).addTo(this.map);
}

ionViewDidEnter() {
    this.filterProvider.getData(resource).subscribe(data => {
      if (this.map !== null) {
        L.geoJSON(osmtogeojson(data), {
          style: function(feature) {
              return {
                color: "#0288D1"
              };
          },
          pointToLayer: function(feature, latlng) {
            return L.marker(latlng, {
              icon: L.icon({
                iconUrl: 'assets/map/' + resource.toLowerCase() +'.png'
              })
            });
          },
          onEachFeature: function(feature, layer) {
            layer.bindPopup(JSON.stringify(feature.properties));
          }
        }).addTo(this.map);
      }
    });
}

ionViewDidLeave() {
   this.map = null;
   this.selectedResource = null;
}
```

Comment: "_putting a lot of Markers on the map_" how many typically? This may be the reason for your page freezing.

Answer (score 1):

some time ago I published in codigo200 blog, an example of Ionic3 + Leaflet that solves your problem. The code is in github, you can read the explanation [here](https://codigo200.wordpress.com/2017/11/25/mapas-con-ionic-2-3-leaflet-y-marcadores/).

```
// atributes

map: L.Map;
center: L.PointTuple;
tempIcon: any;

ionViewDidLoad() {

this.center = [23.03, -81.57]; //a place in Cuba

this.map = L.map('map', {
center: this.center,
zoom: 13
});

//Adicionamos la ruta de OSM.
L.tileLayer("http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png", {
attribution: '&copy; Código 200'
})
.addTo(this.map);

this.mensaje("Pulse sobre un punto en el mapa para añadir un nuevo lugar");

this.tempIcon = L.icon({
iconUrl: 'assets/imgs/marker.png',
shadowUrl: '',
iconSize: [32, 32], // size of the icon
shadowSize: [0, 0], // size of the shadow
iconAnchor: [32, 32], // point of the icon which will correspond to markers location
shadowAnchor: [0, 0], // the same for the shadow
popupAnchor: [32, 20] // point from which the popup should open relative to the iconAnchor
});

this.map.on('click', (e) => { this.onMapClick(e) });

}

onMapClick(e) {
let tempMarker = L.marker(e.latlng, { icon: this.tempIcon })
.on('click', this.showMarkerMenu, this)  // Al hacer click, ejecutamos this.showMarkerMenu y le pasamos el contexto (this)
.addTo(this.map);

this.mensaje("Coordinate: " + e.latlng);

}
```

So, I hope that solves your problem, remember that you need link leaflet in index.html.